# Hola Necesito alguien me diga que tipo de codificación es esta: ¨ZMso:!BZk\x0000.0.0.0\x01true\x01¨

Tags: codificación

Hola Necesito alguien me diga que tipo de codificación es esta la tome del PopMessenger: `ZMso:!BZk\x0000.0.0.0\x01true\x01`

Comment: "ZMso" me late que es SAP

Comment: creo que si, tienes algun codigo en python, para eso?

Comment: No. Mira la documentación, edita tu pregunta que no está claro lo que se pregunta. Falta detallar mucho para poder reproducir tu escenario.

Comment: lo que quiero hacer es poder ver atraves de un script en python los usuario que estan usando el Popmessenger y poder enviarles algún mensaje, esto se puede hacer ?

Comment: Si existe una API, lo más probable es que sea posible. Desconzo SAP